# High copy speed at begining of copying

Tags: 16.04, usb, dd, copy, cp

When I copy file (doesn't mater which process I use - krusader, cp, dd, ...) firstly its very fast, like way too fast (around 7000 MB/s to USB 2.0 pen-drive). Then it suddenly slows down (usually at 99%) and almost freezes for few minutes. My guess is, that first part is copied to some cache and then it synchronizes to USB by normal speed.

Problem is shown here, when I test drive performance (`/dev/sdb` is USB 2.0 pen-drive):

```
$ sudo hdparm -Tt /dev/sdb

/dev/sdb:
Timing cached reads:   14654 MB in  2.00 seconds = 7332.19 MB/sec
Timing buffered disk reads:  64 MB in  3.05 seconds =  20.97 MB/sec
```

[This bug is maybe related](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nautilus/+bug/1208993):

Laptop: Ubuntu 16.04 (4.10.0-42-generic), Awesome WM, 16G RAM, 512 SSD, ...
(this is not first time I encounter this - the same problem had my older laptop also with 16G RAM)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you may be experiencing the bug mentioned, but it may be normal operation also.

At first the system writes to the drive cache, which can be very fast depending on memory bus speed. When the cache gets to a certain point, it starts pushing pages to disk while still receiving writes to cache. Since disk write is much slower than memory writes, cache will eventually fill. When this happens the system flushes the cache to disk and begins writing directly to disk. Depending on cache size, this flush can take a a while to process.

As mentioned in the bug report you linked, changing 'dirty ratio' can reduce this lag.